# Bitbucket ssh public denied

Tags: linux, git, ssh

Ok so I've run out almost on every idea and tutorial I can find online.

So basically I have a Bitbucket repo and I want to set it up to automaticly update my linux server each time someone pushes to the repo.

I was trying to follow this [Tutorial](http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2013/11/19/automated-git-deployments-from-bitbucket/) but at step 1 ssh, I failed to do anything.

I made an ssh key on my linux server. After that opened the .pub one I got and copied its content to my BitBucket acc.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

After the pub key has been added I verified that it is working by doing this:

```
ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
```

And I get a response to add the hosts keyfingerpint and everything is OK and I get my username returned that is using that key.

After that the tutorial said to make a config file in .ssh folder

```
Host bitbucket.org
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket_rsa
```

After that it said to try and clone the repo to my server from BitBucket.
And that's were I get the error.

```
****@Main:/var/www/repo$ sudo git clone git@bitbucket.org:******/******.git
Cloning into '******'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

If anyone can help me I would be more than grateful seeing that I really have run out of ideas what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your said config is in your own `.ssh` folder, but the clone operation is performed as root (via `sudo`). So this key isn't relevant and not considered for this operation.

You should copy and activate the key in `/root`.

Comment: That's probably the stupidest mistake I have ever made. Thank you sir! You deserve a beer!

Answer (score 0):

Then the public key isn't set correctly in your Bitbucket account.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git

> Step 6. Install the public key on your Bitbucket account

Go to Step 6 and upload your public key to Bitbucket. Then you should have access to your repo.

Edit:

To use your private key you should change your rights to `600` for your id_rsa file otherwise your system can't load the key.

Comment: It is added. As I said that part is not the problem.